# Joining tables and returning data to react with Spring JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to join two entities in Spring JPA so that I can access the data in react.

I have an `Event` and `Course` entity with corresponding tables in postgres.

In react I loop through all the events in the database and display them on a card for each event. The Event table contains the `courseid` where that event is being played at. But I want to show on the card the `coursename` rather than the `courseid`.

I dont currently have access to this so need to join the tables so I have access to it.

I have never used queries in Spring JPA and struggling to create one to make this join.

I want something like this SQL query,

```
select * from event join course on course.courseid=event.course_id where eventid=5
```

where the `eventid` will be passed from react to Spring so that during each loop, it will get the correct `eventid` and display the corresponding `coursename` for that event.

Answer (score 2):

Implementation:

```java
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Course {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "courseid")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "coursename")
    private String courseName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course")
    private List<Event> events;

    // ...
}
```

```java
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Event {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "eventid")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    private Course course;

    // ...
}
```

```java
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Long> {
}
```

Usage:

```java
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private EventRepository eventRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public Map<String, ? extends Object> index(@RequestParam("id") final long id) {

        // find by eventid
        final Optional<Event> res = eventRepository.findById(id);

        res.ifPresent(e -> {
            // course name
            System.out.println(e.getCourse().getCourseName());
        });

        return res.map(e -> Map.of("id", e.getId(), "course", e.getCourse().getCourseName()))
            .orElse(Map.of());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added this next to mapping, ("/management/events/courseDetails/{id:[0-9]+}") and changed RequestParam to PathVariable so that I can pass the eventid in the api call from react. It works in postman and returns the name of the course.